# Color Picker - Not finding the correct color value OpenCV3 Python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to code a **Color Picker** function with OpenCV Python.

Inside `getColor` function, I retrieve the coordinates of the mouse click (*x*,*y*) and access the pixel of the input image corresponding to these coordinates. However, the retrieved color doesn't seem to be the color of the pixel I click on.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

TrackColor = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def getColor(event,x,y,flags,param):

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        print('x:',x,'y:',y)
        d = img[x][y]
        b,g,r = d
        TrackColor[:] = [b,g,r]
        print(d)

cv2.namedWindow('frame')

cv2.setMouseCallback('frame',getColor)


while(1):

    ret, img = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Color',TrackColor)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing the `img` matrix properly.

A matrix is accessed like so: `img[row][col]`

In your code `x` is the *column*'s index and `y` the *row*'s index,
so change your code to: `img[y][x]`

---

*This is indeed an easy question (that you could've figured yourself). Please, next time try to search on the internet for a little bit longer before posting a question.*

Comment: @PigiBouxx In your code, when your mouse was pointing for instance (_x_:155, _y_:210) you were reading the pixel at `img[155][210]`, or in other words the pixel at (_x_:210, _y_:155), so not the correct pixel.

Comment: Yes i know, i have changed that, so the syntax is img[y][x] ? Or its my bad, and i make a error on the code